# when remove an element of ArrayList from inside for each loop. its break the loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

when remove an element of `ArrayList` from inside `foreach` loop. its break the loop.
throw ConcurrentModificationException
My question is why its break the loop.

Code.

```
ArrayList gStudyLst=getLst();
    int recordCount=0;
    for(String study : gStudyLst){
        if(++recordCount < 10){
            if(generateFile(study)){
                gStudyLst.remove(study); // there its break throw ConcurrentModificationException
            }else{
                System.out.println("File not generated"):
                gStudyLst.clear();
                return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use Iterator.remove() or an indexed remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to avoid **ConcurrentModificationException**.

Java doc of the `Iterator` interface says:

> Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying
>   collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.

Here is an example:

```
Iterator<String> iter = myArrayList.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = iter.next();

    if (someCondition)
        iter.remove();
}
```

Comment: iter.remove() can remove element from myArrayList?

Comment: @Pawanmishra : Yes it can.

Answer (score 2):

It is because "The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future."

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

for each loop is just used to iterate through the values of the arraylist. If you want to remove values inside the loop, use iterator as shown below

```
for (Iterator iterator = gStudyLst.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String study = (String) iterator.next();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for statement has the form:

`for ( Type Identifier : Expression ) Statement`

The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

`for (I iter = Expression.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Type Identifier = iter.next();
    Statement
}`

From javaDoc:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException

So instead of using `forEach` use `Iterater` and modify your List using the iterator's own remove or add methods.